# Restricting editing on Word tables

Tags: vba, ms-word

Good day,

Hope someone can help...

I am generating a Word document using inhouse software that has very limited functionality.
Luckily, I can call macros using this software but unfortunately, I do not know too much about creating them...

The document I am generating has tables of results which are generated in the system. Users need to be able to add to the document but not change any of the existing tables.
I found that I can do this buy locking the entire document with something like:

```
myDoc.Protect wdAllowOnlyReading
```

How can only do this to the tables?

My plan was to select everything else and then

```
Selection.Editors.Add wdEditorEveryone
```

But I dont know how to select all text other than the text in tables.

I could also wrap all the other text in brackets for example {} and then make text editable if between those brackets?

Thanks! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Read about content controls - with that functionality you can lock special areas very easy

Comment: You could cycle through your tables and apply a group content control to each table. You could set the properties of that control to not allow its deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments, I was able to use controls to do this fairly easily!
Thank you Ike and Charles :)

This is what I ended up with (I think there might be some extra stuff thats not needed but works!) :

```
Sub LOCKTABLES()

Dim doc As Document
Set doc = ActiveDocument

Dim intCount As Integer
intCount = doc.Tables.Count

Dim iTable As Integer
For iTable = 1 To intCount
    Dim source_Table_Range As Range
    Set source_Table_Range = doc.Tables(iTable).Range
    source_Table_Range.Select
    source_Table_Range.ContentControls.Add (wdContentControlGroup)
    Selection.ParentContentControl.LockContentControl = True
Next
 If ActiveDocument.Saved = False Then ActiveDocument.Save

End Sub
```